# MTP and Thunar: HTC One via USB

Tags: android, xfce, mtp, manjaro, thunar

I googled for a while and still don't have my HTC One listed in Thunar. What I tried:

- turn off debugger mode on phone
- connected the phone to different USB-ports as I read that it might not work with certain versions of USB
- created file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` which hadn't existed before and inserted

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
  ```
- these commands:

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl restart systemd-udevd
  $ sudo systemctl restart systemd-udev-trigger
  $ sudo lsusb
  $ sudo mtp-detect
  ```
- rebooted my machine occasionally
- installed `jmtpfs` and `android-udev`

None of these made me believe that Linux recognized the phone. Note that I didn't try all of the possible combinations possible with the above things to do. Feel free to point out what "has to work".

What I want is that

1. Linux finds the phone when I connect it
2. I can make it accessible like any other directory somehow
3. Linux/Thunar ideally does all of this automatically

I'm using Manjaro with XFCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing these: gvfs-mtp for MTP or gvfs-gphoto2, worked for me on archlinux.

> # pacman -S gvfs-mtp gvfs-gphoto2

Comment: I had completely forgotten about this question... At some point it started to work and I can't recall why. But yes, I have these two packages installed.